# Hierarchical Select, exposed filter, taxonomy,associated with at least one node

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, hierarchical, drupal-exposed-filter

Hello evrey body and thanks for any one can help me in advanced.
im using Hierarchical Select in exposed filter views 2.
how can i configure my exposed filter to not show all taxonomies in the select list of the filter , i want from it to show taxonomies with with at least one node associated.
i have tired enabling this option from Hierarchical Select inside the vocabulary
and i got this error

```
user warning: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') count_alias' at line 1 query: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM () count_alias in C:\wamp\www\8keys\sites\all\modules\hierarchical_select\modules\hs_taxonomy_views.module on line 556.
```

and i also want to ask if i can use the same techinque but with cck field instead of taxonomy ,
i mean country : i dont want to show in the search list the list of countries with at least one node associated.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Check out this module. It should narrow your list of terms only to used ones.
http://drupal.org/project/views_hacks#views_filters_selective